# Is possible company will let go background check

Tags: human-resources, contracts, background-check, developer

I have been employed by my company for 5 months now as a developer and they have a client that asked to have every employee with access to customer data checked with a background check. They are trying to get my high school diploma and transcript and the school and the government refuse to give it to them. Is it possible they will let it go? I've signed every contract and paper so they could have access to those files and still they can't get their hands on it. What can I do? I am tired of signing things if they can't get the information. It is not my fault, what should I do??

My references are good and I have no criminal record.

Comment: When dealing with PII the primary things that they should be interested in are criminal records, work history and credit history.  A copy of your HS diploma and transcript seems a bit much unless you are working on classified government systems.  However if that was the case they wouldn't have a problem getting the info.  I wouldn't worry about this.

Answer (score 8):

I would keep signing whatever they ask you to (with regards to the background check) and also offer to make phone calls or requests on their behalf.

You could also try going to the offices yourself to try to get a certified copy.

It's important that you don't give up trying to help them or (if they are the more paranoid sort) they may start to believe that you're somehow behind the stonewalling.

Most importantly, keep expressing your willingness to do whatever you can to assist them in getting the information they desire.

Answer (score -1):

Limit yourself to 100% cooperation. If their efforts to get the documentation are not successful, they need to stop and ask for something that the government can cooperate with. Do NOT take ownership of this issue - do NOT volunteer in any way to turn their self-inflicted headache into yours.

Comment: I think it is better to have to spend 3 hours on the phone with the government trying to get a piece of paper than getting fired because you can't work for the customer because you won't spend time trying to get the paper.

Comment: @PeterMaidens I would intervene only if my intervention makes a difference and only if the company represents to me that my intervention would make a difference. Otherwise, it's YOUR life, YOUR time, YOUR aggravation, YOUR frustration and you can do whatever the hell you want to do with them. If I sent you a message that I am standing between the wall and your desire to bang your head against it, then I am sent the wrong message. I applied twice for a security clearance and each time, I nearly went insane.